# How to remove code duplication when implementing interfaces that share common methods

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

*EDIT
Ive rephrased the question so it better reflects what im trying to do*

I'm trying to create a suite of classes that all inherit from 1 "superclass" or "baseclass".

However i'm looking for a way around having to implement the code for each method, in every single class since it seems to be theres a lot of duplication.

Here is the Super class:

```
public abstract class WebObject
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }

    public void Click() { Console.WriteLine("Clicking object"); }
    public string GetAttribute() { return "An attribute"; }
    public void SetAttribute(string attribute, string value)
    {
        //code to set attribute
    }
}
```

I've also created a couple of interfaces:

```
interface IReadable
{
    string GetText();
}

interface IWriteable
{
    void SetText(string value);
}
```

Here is an example derived class:

```
public class TextBox: WebObject, IWriteable, IReadable
{


}
```

Of course the above class contains an error. It does not implement IWriteable or IReadable.

So I could do something like:

```
public class TextBox: WebObject, IWriteable, IReadable
{
    public void SetText(string value)
    {
        //Implemented code
    }

    public string GetText()
    {
        //Implemented code
        return "some value";
    }
}
```

Which would compile fine...
However the problem here is that SetText and GetText contain a lot of code. I don't want to have to copy this every single time I want to implement the method. Id rather just write the code once and have it called any time I need to use that method.

I know we cant do multiple inheritance in C# and Java. So my original thought was simply to create a suite of static classes with the code for SetText and GetText Shown here:

```
public static class Setter
{
    public static void SetText(string value)
    {
        //Code to set text
    }
}

public static class Getter
{
    public static string GetText()
    {
        //Code to get text
        return "";
    }
}
```

Then changing my TextBox class to the following:

```
public class TextBox: WebObject, IWriteable, IReadable
{
    public void SetText(string value)
    {
        Setter.SetText(value);
    }

    public string GetText()
    {
        return Getter.GetText();
    }
}
```

I cant help but feel this is a pretty long winded solution. It accomplishes what I want in that TextBox has the vanilla methods plus the 2 it implements itself.

But my question is, can I achieve the same goal using a more concise design?

*Footnotes*

*Each object actually implements several of common methods. Take TextBox, ComboBox and SelectBox they all should be able to SetText, however only CombBox and SelectBox should be able to use Select.*

Comment: That won't work if you access any kind of state.

Comment: What do `SetText` and `GetText` do? If you have a static implementation for them, why would you need instance methods that do the same thing?

Comment: Maybe you can move part of your code to a C++ project. There you can have multiple inheritance and expose the interfaces...

Comment: SetText sets the text value of a web object.
GetText gets the text

Comment: @SLaks I dont understand. Can you elaborate more on what you mean by accessing a state?

Comment: Please explain why, if this code is to be shared among all the subclasses, you don't just put it all in the base class (including the interface declarations). As it stands right now, it's not really clear what you're even asking, as the most obvious interpretation of your question also comes with a very obvious solution.

Comment: @Peter some elements are different. For example a TextBox and CombBox implement different methods.

They each can get and set attributes and be clicked however ComboBox can also have Select

Comment: Your code has been simplified to the point where the problem isn't clear. Your `SetText` and `GetText` aren't really `void` with no parameters, correct?

Comment: _"some elements are different"_ -- that doesn't explain anything. Your question specifically says _"theres_ [sic] _a lot of duplication"_. If there are elements that are different, then obviously those are not what we are discussing, because "different" is the opposite of "duplication". Polymorphism is good for dealing with "different" when the basic interface is the same; base class is good for dealing with "duplication". There's no reason you can't mix both techniques.

Comment: I see your point peter. But say TextBox uses SetText, so does ComboBox and ListBox as does Calendar.

Which means I have 4 classes all using SetText. However I cannot put it in the base class as not all derived classes can use it.

Take the Span class for example. This cannot implement SetText, It can only use GetText plus the base class methods

Comment: Normally you'd just make an abstract class to hold your Getter and Setter functions and then inherit that in the classes that need it (ie, your TextBox, ComboBox, ListBox, and Calendar). Then your C# code could just use the `as` on your object, and if the new `as`'d variable instance was not null, then the code could plug away.

Comment: Oh, the joy of trying to reuse code in an OO language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way to do what you are asking is to implement `protected` helper methods within your base class that decompose the problem of "a lot of duplication" into smaller pieces that can be composed in your concrete method implementations, like this:

```
public abstract class WebObject {
  protected void SetTextImpl() { /* Implementation */ } 
  protected void GetTextImpl() { /* Implementation */ } 
}
```

Then in your derived classes, implement only the applicable interfaces and appropriate methods:

```
public class TextBox: WebObject, IWriteable, IReadable {
  public void SetText() { SetTextImpl(); }
  public void GetText() { GetTextImpl(); }
}

public class Span: WebObject, IReadable {
  public void GetText() { GetTextImpl(); }
}
```

If you know that all the subclasses will be IReadable, you can simplify further:

```
public abstract class WebObject : IReadable {
  protected void SetTextImpl() { /* Implementation */ } 
  protected void GetTextImpl() { /* Implementation */ } 

  // Implement IReadable -- this could be combined with GetTextImpl() but
  // is implemented separately for consistency.
  public void GetText() { GetTextImpl(); }
}

public class TextBox: WebObject, IWriteable {
  public void SetText() { SetTextImpl(); }
}

public class Span: WebObject, IReadable {
}
```

Comment: I prefer this solution the most. It looks a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

If the code for those two methods will always be the same or mostly the same, you could create another abstract class (ex: WebObjectReadWrite) that inherits from WebObject and implements the interface.

```
public abstract class WebObjectReadWrite : WebObject, IReadable, IWritable
{
    // Could be made virtual if some subclasses need to overwrite default implementation.
    public void Read() 
    {
        // Implementation
    }

    // Could be made virtual if some subclasses need to overwrite default implementation.
    public void Write() 
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}

public class TextBox : WebObjectReadWrite
{
}
```

This could, however, lead to multiple inheritance problems or inheritance relationships that don't make sense. Another option is to use the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) (in way) to delegate the read / write operations to other classes that can be reused.

```
public class TextBox : WebObject, IReadable, IWriteable
{
    private IReadable _readable = new TextReader();
    private IWriteable _writeable = new TextWriter();

    public void Read() 
    {
        _readable.Read();
    }

    public void Write() 
    {
        _writable.Write();
    }
}

public class Span : WebObject, IReadable
{
    // Reused class.
    private IReadable _readable = new TextReader();        

    public void Read() 
    {
        _readable.Read();
    }
}

public class TextReader : IReadable
{
    public void Read()
    {
        // Reusable implementation
    } 
}
```

This isn't quite the strategy pattern because you are not allowing the caller to choose the implementation of IReadable and IWriteable. However, it does allow you to reuse IReadable and IWriteable classes.

Comment: The second option provided is close enough to what I would have suggested myself. Create a new class/interface that does the settext/gettext and inject an instance of it into each class that needs the functionality. Then call that instance directly. It might still feel like "waste" since one method may directly calls another, but your application will be much more extensible and decoupled.